# Magento Product Page scrolls down automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, scroll

I use the magento kallyas theme and there must be some javascript that forces all my product pages to scroll down automatically.

This page: http://www.stainer-online.com/produkte/tische/altholztische/altholztisch-design-silbermine.html

When you load this page, or reload it or choose a other product-detail-page your browser scrolls down.

Which script or extension is this? Themedevelopers cant help.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

probably this in fault in your js :

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(pos){
    if (! pos)
        pos = 'fixed';

    var w = jQuery(window);
    this.css("position", pos);
    if ('fixed' == pos){
        this.css("top" , (w.height()-this.height())/2 + "px");
        this.css("left", (w.width()-this.width())  /2 + "px");
    } else if ('absolute' == pos){
        this.css("top",(w.height()-this.height())/2+w.scrollTop() + "px");
        if(w.height() < this.height())
            this.css("top", w.scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left",(w.width()-this.width())/2+w.scrollLeft() + "px");
    }
    return this;
}
```

Try not to force the top attribute in css, and maybe the position as well.

Comment: Nope. I already tried to remove that. No change. I also tried to search vor "scroll" and "focus".

Comment: this.css("top", w.scrollTop() + "px"); Please comment out this line and check.

Comment: shure. i removed it only for testing. There was no change so i leaved it.

Comment: must be somewere in a js file